# Why is the regular Taylor expansion so similar to the construction of the Hamiltonian from a Lagrangian/Legendre transform?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, differentiation, calculus

An example of a first order Taylor expansion of a function with two variables is given by:
$$f\left(x,y\right)=f\left(x_0,y_0\right)+\left(x-x_0\right)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\left(y-y_0\right)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$
For $x_0=0,\ y_0=0$ we get:
$$f\left(x,y\right)=\left(x\right)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\left(y\right)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+f\left(0,0\right)$$
This looks really similar to the relation between Hamiltonian and Lagrangian (which is obviously the Legendre transform):
$$H=\dot{q}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q}}+{\dot{q}}_2\frac{\partial L}{\partial{\dot{q}}_2}-L$$
Is the Hamiltonian just an application of a Taylor expansion of the Lagrangian? Why is the minus sign there?

EDIT: I have a lot of downvotes, I do not understand why. I adjusted my question to include the fact that I know it is a legendre transform but my question extends to that as well. I hope someone can explain me what I am missing, pardon me if it is elementary.

Comment: No it’s not a Taylor expansion, rather it is the *Legendre transform*.

Comment: But why has this question been downvoted 4 times? Please, somebody, explain the reason to a mere mortal like me.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I adjusted my question. Why is the construction and the Legendre transform so similar to a taylor expansion? Is the Legendre transform basically a taylor expansion?

Answer (score 0):

No, Legendre transforms are not the same as Taylor expansions. Well ok, so derivatives are by definition linear approximations, and by definition of Taylor polynomials, the first-order term is by definition the same as the first derivative (but really, thinking of first derivatives as Taylor expansions is not really the best way to go since you mix up a non-trivial theorem with a simple definition).

Anyway, the ‘goal’ of Legendre transforms is to change a set of variables using derivatives as independent variables. More precisely, suppose I have a smooth function $f:\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^k\to\Bbb{R}$. Let us write the coordinates as $(x,y)=(x^1,\dots, x^n,y^1,\dots, y^k)$. For such a function, its differential (exterior derivative) is
\begin{align}
df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\,dx^i+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^{\alpha}}\,dy^{\alpha}.
\end{align}
Here, our independent variables are $(x,y)$. But let’s say we want to change that, by no longer using $y^{\alpha}$ as independent variables, instead using $p_{\alpha}:=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^{\alpha}}$ as an independent variable. Then, by ‘integration by parts’ (really just product rule in reverse), we have
\begin{align}
df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\,dx^i+p_{\alpha}\,dy^{\alpha}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\,dx^i+d(y^{\alpha}p_{\alpha})-y^{\alpha}\,dp_{\alpha},
\end{align}
or rearranging,
\begin{align}
d(y^{\alpha}p_{\alpha}-f)&=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\,dx^i+y^{\alpha}\,dp_{\alpha}.\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
So, we have expressed the differential of the function $\lambda_{f}:=y^{\alpha}p_{\alpha}-f$ purely in terms of linear combinations of $dx^i$ and $dp_{\alpha}$, meaning we can consider the function $\lambda_f$ ‘purely as a function of $(x,p)$’. Or perhaps another way of saying it is that the 1-form on the right of $(*)$ is exact, meaning it can be ‘integrated’ to yield a function of $(x,p)$. Notice carefully that the minus sign here is traced back to doing the product rule in reverse. This new function $\lambda_f$ is then called the *Legendre transform* of $f$.

---

More precisely, what we mean when we say we’re ‘considering $p_{\alpha}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^{\alpha}}$ as an independent variable’ is that we consider the mapping $\Phi:\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^k\to\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^k$ given by
\begin{align}
\Phi(x,y)&=\left(x,\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\right)\equiv\left(x^1,\dots, x^n,\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^1}(x,y),\dots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y^k}(x,y)\right).
\end{align}
This map $\Phi$ is called the *fiber derivative of $f$* (in the literature, this is also sometimes confusingly referred to as the Legendre transform of $f$, but we reserve this terminology for something else). Then, our hope is that the function $\Phi$ has a smooth inverse $\Phi^{-1}$ (this is locally guaranteed by the inverse function theorem if the Hessian $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}$ of $f$ with respect to the $y$ variables is invertible). Then the meaning of ‘considering things as functions of $(x,p)$’ is that we compose by $\Phi^{-1}$ everywhere appropriately. The precise way of writing $(*)$ is that
\begin{align}
d((y^{\alpha}\circ\Phi^{-1})\cdot p_{\alpha}-f\circ\Phi^{-1})=-\frac{\partial(f\circ\Phi^{-1})}{\partial x^i}\,dx^i+(y^{\alpha}\circ\phi^{-1})\,dp_{\alpha}.
\end{align}
So, it is the function $\lambda_f:= (y^{\alpha}\circ\Phi^{-1})\cdot p_{\alpha}-f\circ\Phi^{-1}$, which is defined on a ‘completely different copy of $\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^k$’ which is called the *Legendre transform of $f$*. See [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4237975/568204) for the general (coordinate-free) description at the level of vector bundles.

---

The ‘similarity’ you claim in your comments is superficial (in my eyes non-existent), and perhaps it’s because you’re reading too much into the differential formula $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z^j}\,dz^j$ for a function $f(z_1,\dots, z_l)$, and looking at everything from the coordinate perspective. I mention this once again: we’re not Taylor expanding anything. We are starting from one function $f$, and defining a completely new function $\lambda_f$ defined on a completely different space (the fact that it is defined on a new space, is what we intuitively mean when we say ‘new set of independent variables’). The mapping $f\mapsto \lambda_f$ can then be called the *Legendre transformation*. Once you look at the formulation in my link above, you’ll see that everything is defined on completely different spaces, so the Legendre transform is a truly non-trivial process, converting one function to another new one (compared to the simple theorem of differential calculus, which is Taylor’s theorem).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain the answer